# Why does the moonbeam/moonriver polkadot-js website not have an extrinsics developer menu?

Tags: moonbeam, moonriver, curiosity-killed-the-cat

Why does the moonbeam/moonriver polkadot-js websites not have an extrinsics developer menu? The chain state can be queried, and RPC seems there.

I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apps only show certain functions, including the extrinsics tab, when you have at least one account.

Because Moonbeam uses Ethereum-style accounts instead of Polkadot accounts, your existing Polkadot account set to be used on all chains doesn't count as a Moonbeam account.

Instead, you will need to create a new account in the polkadot.js apps for Moonbeam. Once this is done, the extrinsics tab appears just as it does for other chains.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that I learned: even when a particular parachain does not explicitly show the extrinsics menu item on [polkadot.js.org/apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps), the webpage is still accessible if you simply add `#/extrinsics` to the end of the URL, and it is fully functional as well! See the screecap below:

[image: Screencap of PolkadotJS on the extrinsics page]

Comment: cute - nice trick.